# TextFrame.AutoSize not fitting automatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint, autosize

I'm using VBA in powerpoint.

I executed following code and AutoSize doesn't work.

A page is created, title and textbox is created into this page.
Textbox doesn't fit automatically.

Please help me.

```vb
Sub page_create()
    Dim myPresentation As Presentation
    Dim mySlide As Slide
    
    Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation
    'There are 1st slide before!!
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Examples"
    Set prevShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    Set myTextbox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, prevShape.Left, prevShape.Top + prevShape.Height, 0, 0)
    
    myTextbox.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
    myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "list, set, int, float, str, tuple"
```

I changed the order of following sentences, but it doesn't work.

```
myTextbox.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "list, set, int, float, str, tuple"
```

I referenced [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textframe.autosize)

Answer (score 0):

adding `myTextbox.TextFrame.WordWrap = False` worked for me.

```
Sub page_create()


    Dim myPresentation As Presentation
    Dim mySlide As Slide
    
    Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation
    'There are 1st slide before!!
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Examples"
    Set prevShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    Set myTextbox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, prevShape.Left, prevShape.Top + prevShape.Height, 0, 0)
    
    myTextbox.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
    myTextbox.TextFrame.WordWrap = False'here
    myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "list, set, int, float, str, tuple"
    
End Sub
```